# How to apply decoupling on these two coupled classes

Tags: java, oop, circular-dependency

I have two classes:

```
public class CourseModule {

  // attributes...

  List<Course> courses;

  public void addCourse() { ... }
}

public class Course {

  // attributes...

  CourseModule module;
}
```

The attributes of `Course` do not suffice to identify an object uniquely, the course module is always required, also for addition information. A `CourseModule` consists of difference `Courses`.

What I don't like here is the **circular dependency**, it feels wrong. Now I was thinking about the following, instead of adding courses per method and setting the `CourseModule` reference by hand I could automate this procedure with the constructor:

```
public Course(...,...,...., CourseModule module) {

   this.module = module;
   module.courses.add(this);
}
```

But again, here is another huge problem: In Brian Goetz Java Concurrency in Practice it is said: **Do not let the `this` reference escape the constructor**

So what would be best practice here? I think its a really simple example, which might bear yield a sample solution.

Comment: Does the Course need to know its CourseModule?

Comment: How about in `courses.add(new Cource(..., this))` in module? What you are setting up is a bi-directional parent-child (or container-containee) relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough, I had to do something similar. See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086529/programming-a-one-to-many-relationship).

I found [this post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-objrel3/index.html) on the internet that is almost an exact duplicate of what you are trying to do, also with courses! I found that the solution specified there is not 100% right, the answers on my question need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I would say that your current setup is an example of [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Could you not make another object `CourseInfo` that manages the additional course information that you say cannot be contained within `Course`?

```
public class CourseModule {

    List<Course> courses;

    public void addCourse(Course course) { ... }
}

public class Course {

    CourseInfo info;
}

public class CourseInfo {

    CourseInfo info;
}
```